# Debugging a local spark executor in pycharm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I want to step through the work of a spark executor running locally on my machine, from Pycharm.

I am running explicit functionality, in the form of `dataset.foreachPartition(f)` 
and I want to see what is going on inside `f`.

Is there a straightforward way to do it or do I need to resort to remote debugging?

Comment: are you using community pycharm edition or entreprise?